# What is the purpose of using MicrosoftAppPassword in appsettings.json?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

All.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-authentication-types

According to the figure described in the link above, I guess that the authentication flow between Bot Connector Service and Bot is as below.

1. Bot Connector Service gets an access token from AzureAD with MicrosoftAppID and MicrosoftAppPassword.
2. Bot Connector Service sends the token generated in No.1 to Bot with Authorization Header.
3. Bot validates the token and confirm that audience field in JWT Token contains MicrosoftAppID

In this flow, It seems that Bot does not use MicrosoftAppPassword defined in Bot Application's appsettings.json.

Is it required to define MicrosoftAppPassword in appsettings.json? What is the purpose of using MicrosoftAppPassword in appsettings.json?

Answer (score 0):

For single and multi tenant bots, the bot must have both the AppId and the AppPassword to be able to authenticate itself to the Bot Connector Service. Without the AppPassword, the bot **cannot** communicate with Azure.

The only exception is a Managed Identity, which is an authentication mechanism that is managed by Azure across multiple resources, as the name implies. When using one of these, you do not supply an AppPassword.